# Why wont my custom cursor work?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cursor, customization

I'm just trying to make the cursor a custom image. I have followed all instructions everywhere but it still will not work:

CSS:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    cursor: url(images/rsz_red_crosshair.gif), crosshair;
}
```

The image is 32x32. The stylesheet is linked properly because the border is showing. The second option (the built in crosshair) works fine. Just wondering what I'm doing wrong, I'm sure it's fairly obvious to others.

Comment: i think your image path is not correct http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/fL2qL4k2/ it works for me

Comment: change you image path to `url(../images/rsz_red_crosshair.gif)`

Comment: Yep, that is correct, i knew it was something obvious even though i looked for like an hour. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your style syntax is correct and I've implemented it myself just to be sure.  I would confirm the location of your image.

Answer (score 0):

This css should solve your problem. Include the URL in quotation mark and make sure path is correct.

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width:100%;
    cursor: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/plastic-mini/32/Cursor-icon.png'), auto;
}
```